# I need help to make right, left and mid text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a banner like this I have my banner code.

[image]

```
<div class="main-content__title_black" 
     data-swiper-parallax-opacity="0.2" 
     data-swiper-parallax="-150" style=" color: #ffffff;"> Forex</div

<div class="main-content__text_black" 
     data-swiper-parallax-opacity="0.2" 
     data-swiper-parallax="-300" style=" color: #ffffff;"> The FX market is the market in which participants can buy, sell and exchange currencies. </div>
<div class="main-content__text_black3" 
     data-swiper-parallax-opacity="0.2" 
     data-swiper-parallax="-550" style=" color: #ffffff; font-size: 60px; "> V/S</div
```

I need to make right and left text with VS on mid

Answer (score 0):

**Use css flexbox properties**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.block {
width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="main-content__title_black block" 
     data-swiper-parallax-opacity="0.2" 
     data-swiper-parallax="-150" style="color: '#ffffff;'"> Forex</div>
     
     <div class="main-content__text_black3 block" 
     data-swiper-parallax-opacity="0.2" 
     data-swiper-parallax="-550" style="color: '#ffffff'; font-size: 60px; "> V/S</div>

<div class="main-content__text_black block" 
     data-swiper-parallax-opacity="0.2" 
     data-swiper-parallax="-300" style="color: '#ffffff;'"> The FX market is the market in which participants can buy, sell and exchange currencies. </div>
</div>
```

For more details about css flexbox, you can go to [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: you can run and see the above code snippet, it works. Please go trough CSS flexbox to understand the concept.